# slick carousel divs inside divs

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm using slick.js plugin & it's great but one problem I have is this plugin targets the divs inside the continer right?

But what about if I had divs inside those divs? It mess it up for me like it counts also the inner divs!!

So how do I handle this?

```
<div class="your-class"> 
    <div>your content
        <div>another content!!</div>
    </div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

It supposed to handle only the 'your content' div but that 'another content!!' div mess the layout for me, I suppose because slick count it as a div to the slide or something.

Therefore, there exists any way to have a div inside the div that defines the slide?

Comment: I am sorry what's the problem?

Comment: I don't think there is an issue here

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Found that it's best to change the div to an  tag and if you need remove the default state of the a tag event.preventDefault().

```
<div class="your-class"> 
    <a>your content
        <div>another content!!</div>
    </a>
    <a>your content</a>
    <a>your content</a>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!